# Female-Dominated Undersea World read about in Dictionary of Imaginary Places

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember reading about a fictional place in the dictionary of imaginary places as a child, and I haven't been able to find it since. I remember it was a OLD book, like 1800's or early 1900's, maybe even 1700's.

It was about an undersea society dominated by these female humanoid creatures, described with semi-translucent skin if I remember correctly. There were no male specimens of these, rather the 'males' were small creatures called 'bullpops' which would build towers and try to impress the giant females, who would end up eating them which was how they reproduced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you thinking of *[Capillaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillaria)* by Frigyes Karinthy?

> *Capillaria* (Hungarian: *Capillária*, 1921) is a fantasy novel by Hungarian author Frigyes Karinthy, which depicts an undersea world inhabited exclusively by women, recounts, in a satirical vein reminiscent of the style of Jonathan Swift, the first time that men and women experience sex with one another.
>
> Expressing a pessimistic view of women, the novel suggests that, with disastrous effect, women, who are emotional and illogical, dominate men, the creative, rational force within humanity, who represent the builders of civilization.
>
> The males, known as bullpops, are of small stature. They spend their time building and rebuilding tall, complex, rather phallic towers that the gigantic women destroy as quickly as these structures are erected. Meanwhile, the females engage in sexual adventures, surviving by eating the brains of the miniature men, who have become little more than personified male genitals.

....

> A readily available summary of the relatively rare novel's plot is provided in *[The Dictionary of Imaginary Places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dictionary_of_Imaginary_Places)*.

The book was a sequel to the author's earlier work,  *[Voyage to Faremido: Gulliver's Fifth Voyage](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1135708)* (*Utazás Faremidóba; Gulliver ötödik útja*) as per the accepted answer to [Which Sci-Fi work introduced the concept of an artificial, independent plurality?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133945/23243).

Found by searching for *bullpops*. The full text is [available online](http://mek.oszk.hu/00700/00715/index.phtml), but in Hungarian.

Comment: Wow.... just *wow*! Nice find

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! It was so weird I just couldn't find it for the life of me!

Comment: No worries. Google tunes search results, so that does happen.